# jQuery Change Values Knob

Tags: jquery, audio, html5-audio, jquery-knob

I have made a simple web app where the sine wave volume can be changed with a slider. Not problem.

However, I would like to change the value with a knob, I have tried everything I know (Change, dial, onchange etc.) but nothing seems to work.

```
document.getElementById('black-knob').addEventListener('change', function() {
sample.changeVolume(this);
}); 

$(function() {

        var  value = document.getElementById("black-knob").value;
        $(".knob-values").knobRot({ change : function (value) {    } 

                })
});
```

here there is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RKH35/4/

Could you help me?

what am I missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the plugin you may be able to use the event `knobdrag`.

```
$('#black-knob').on('knobdrag', function(){
    //called until mouse button released
});
```

Comment: yep, I have checked the documentation and tested knobdrag and all other events but its not working, or is just me that i dont implement this events properly.

Comment: It's certainly responding to that event: http://jsfiddle.net/RKH35/4/ check the console while dragging.

Comment: $('#black-knob').on('knobdrag', function(){
                $('.knob-values').val($('#black-knob').knobRot('getvalue'));
                 });  I have tried this but nothing, where do I check the console with coda 2 or chrome . Sorry i have just started using web

Comment: in chrome web browser hit F12 to display the developer tools, console is the last tab.

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to update the input which is already displaying the knob value, with the knob value.

Comment: I have also tried     $('#black-knob').on('knobdrag', function(){ $('changeVolume(this)').val($('#black-knob').knobRot('getvalue')); }); - - - -       also   - - - <input type="text" value="100" id="black-knob" class="knob-values" autocomplete="off" onchange="sample.changeVolume(this);" >

Comment: have you tried to modify the jsfiddle? Is it working?

Comment: The `knobdrag` event handler works, I'm just not sure what you are trying to achieve within the handler? http://jsfiddle.net/DaveParsons/NK6dc/1/

Comment: I just want to use the value to turn volume up or down using the knob instead of the slider.

Comment: I just want to use the value to turn volume up or down using the knob instead of the slider. –

Comment: wow Dave thats very interesting, however the sound should also decrease or increase too ..  I am trying with this function but sound just stops. ---- ----- $('#black-knob').on('knobdrag', function(e) {
        gainNode.gain.value = this.value;
    });

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: gainNode` is not defined - i don't have any experience with the plugins you are using or manipulating sound through the browser so I'm not sure how to help from here. Do you know what `gainNode` should relate to or where it should be defined?

Comment: it is defined here: ---- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://salvonostrato.com//radionics/js/oscillator-sample.js"></script>

Comment: Disclaimer this is all guess work; ideally you should ask the developer of that library! It looks to me like that library expects a `<canvas>` element to be available and then you would need to start the sound using the `play` method. You can change the volume in the `knobdrag` callback using the `changeVolume(element)` method of `OscillatorSample`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have emailed him with no response. I have found the callback function http://jsfiddle.net/NK6dc/6/ --- I have been testing with changeVolume(element) -- the log says: Can't find variable: element..

Comment: Or any Idea why if I change the slider value with the knob the sound does not change?

Comment: Trying passing `$("#black-knob").get(0)` into the `changeVolume` method so: `sample.changeVolume($("#black-knob").get(0));`

Comment: I just get TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.gainNode.gain') if i dont start the sound.  If the sound is on there is no change

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NK6dc/8/  with no errors seems to work but the sound do not change

Comment: Sorry Salvo I'm all out of ideas, perhaps given what you have learnt here you could construct a more specific question that may get more attention?